# Google indexable web static tree component

Tags: seo, web-development

I'm building application with lots of data. I decided to present this data in tree view like control.  Something like Process Explorer

[image]

I'm wondering how to build this to maximize potential to index this data by Google bot. I want data to be well presented but at the same time make it accessable by Google.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: How many pages are you talking about?  If you are talking about 500 or fewer pages then I can see a tree working for both users and search engines.   More pages than that and the data for the tree would get too big to include in every page in your site and you would have to start loading it with AJAX which would be detrimental crawlability.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think you made assumption that this tree is navigation component. It's not like that, I have hierarchical data to present with around 50 hierarchic elements which I would like to present as tree.

Comment: So then all this data is in a single page?    How many megabytes of data is it?   If it is under a couple megabytes, then Zistolen's answer will work fine for you.  More than that and your page may get too large to download.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There will be much less data than 1 MB. Around 150 "tree-rows" with several columns, in static version that I'd like to present to google for indexing. In fact I found solution that may be good: https://web.archive.org/web/20160303203857/http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you represent data tree with lists HTML elements (`<ul>` and `<li>` for example), it shouldn't be a problem for Google idexing.

And if you want to make your tree attractive for users, just play with JavaScript after the HTML is rendered.

Comment: So I should focus on finding js library that can take complex <ul> and <li> structure and make it dynamic. It is heard more and more often that Google execute JavaScript. Is it something that I should bother in this case?

Comment: You can find a JS library to do this or doing by yourself with jQuery for example. And you're right, Google executes JavaScript but not perfectly. If all `<ul>` and `<li>` tags are generated by your server code, you're sure Googlebot will see them and you don't take a risk for indexing.